# Best way to conditionally insert using triggers

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a SQL trigger that inserts a new row if and only if it passes a given condition.  I can think of a couple ways to do this, but I'm not sure which is the best or correct way.

1. Do an AFTER INSERT trigger and then delete the new row if it fails the condition.
2. Do a BEFORE INSERT trigger and raise an application error if it fails.
3. ???

Comment: Might you be better served with a stored procedure that checks the incoming data before performing the insert?

Comment: I do not think it makes any difference in such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 creates a race condition.  I would avoid that explicitly.

Option 2 is likely to cause significantly slower `INSERT`s, but can work.

Option 3 is a stored procedure, but you'll probably need to call the proc for each row inserted, and unless you set up security correctly you may not actually prevent users from inserting data directly.

Option 4 is to insert everything into a staging or transaction table, and then use a broker or procedure with queries or views to move only valid data to the live table.  This is extremely old school and relatively nasty, since you're not using an RDBMS like a modern RDBMS anymore.  Expect lots of problems with key violation issues and synchronization.  And you have the same security problem as Option 3.  This method is usually only used today for bulk import and export.

Option 5 is to validate your data in the application instead of the DB.  This will work, but runs into problems when your customers try to use your RDBMS like an RDBMS.  Then you hit the same security problem as Option 3.  It won't actually fix problems or prevent storage of invalid data by programs outside your application.

Option 6 is to use an RDBMS that supports `CHECK` constraints, which is just about everything not MySQL or MariaDB.  MS SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, even MS Access and SQLite support `CHECK` constraints.  It's moderately ridiculous that MySQL doesn't.